# PostgreSQL - Get rows that match exactly an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I've a `colors` table and an `items` table, with a **many to many** relation between these 2 tables (via an `items_colors` table). An item can have many colors and a color can have many items. And there is no duplicated colors.

```
items
   id

colors
   id
   name

items_colors
    item_id [foreign key: items(id)]
    color_id [foreign key: colors(id)]
```

- How I can get all **items** that have **exactly** a specified **array of colors**? (no more no less)

---

For exemple I want to get all items that have exactly a *blue* **and** a *red* color (if it have another color or just one of the 2 colors, it must be ignored).

I'm still not able to get it... For exemple the query below is returning too much items (for exemple an item that have another color in addition to blue and red).

```sql
SELECT
    i.*,
    array_agg(c.name)
FROM
    items i
    JOIN items_colors ic ON ic.item_id = i.id
    JOIN colors c ON c.id = ic.color_id
WHERE
    c.name IN ('blue', 'red')
GROUP BY
    i.id
HAVING count(DISTINCT c.name) = 2
```

Here is a fiddle to play with my issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9de03c642da5b018d6f20b44bcf91876

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM items i JOIN
     items_colors ic
     ON ic.item_id = i.id JOIN
     colors c
     ON c.id = ic.color_id
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE c.name = ANY (ARRAY['blue', 'red'] ) ) = COUNT(*) AND
       COUNT(*) = CARDINALITY(ARRAY['blue', 'red']);
```

This assumes that neither the data nor the array have duplicates.  It can be tweaked to handle that, but it seems unlikely for this type of problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping me again today! 
There is a syntax error in the `having` part, and I'm not able to catch it. I made a fiddle to test it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8f2a489a594d9fcf046dd0b0640ebaf5

Comment: @Etienne . . . .Missing closing paren.

Comment: Thank you, indeed a paren was missing, but there is still a syntax error. Do we need the `where` keyword in the `filter` syntax? By adding it, the query is working, but there is still too much results (items that have more colors than the queried list of colors is also output). Can you have a look to this dbfiddle please? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc9d9cb401a30d7f9b3ccf830bce6180 Thank again for your help!

Comment: Thanks. The query is now running well, but it still return too much data on some conditions: if an item have more associated colors than the list of queried colors, it is also returned while it shouldn't. This is what is showing the link to the dbfiddle in my comment just above. I am still a beginner in SQL but will try to find a solution. However if you have any idea how to handle this case to make this query fully working, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Etienne . . . That was due to the `WHERE` clause, which I inadvertently left in.

Comment: Right, but as I said in my previous comment, even with the `where` clause this query is returning too much data. Please read again my previous comment or click on this dbfiddle so you will see this query in action with sample data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fc9d9cb401a30d7f9b3ccf830bce6180

Comment: Ok I got it! By playing on different versions of my code, I realised I forgot to remove the previous WHERE clause, before the GROUP BY clause. This is why more data was output. This mistake is visible in the dbfiddle I've provided in my comments above. I'm a beginner in SQL, but also an absent minded person... ;-) Thanks for your precious help and your time.